# Modify the contents in a single slide in beamer class

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, positioning

I have an outline frame with a sidebar (which is a background canvas). Only for this slide I want to move the contents to right side.

For example the current Outline page is as follows:

```
- Section no.1
    * Subsection no.1.1
```

Since there is a sidebar most of the above content overlaps on the side bar.

What I want to do is move the contents a little to the right.

For example the correct Outline page should be as follows:

```
        - Section no.1
            * Subsection no.1.1
```

How can I do it for only one slide. It should be defined in `.sty` files. I tried something as below (without success):

```
%This file defines the basic outline for the beamer theme

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\mode<presentation>

% Aligning the contents of the first frame

\usetitlepagetemplate{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begin{centering}
     \vspace*{-.3cm}
     \fontsize{28}{30}\selectfont {\bf \textcolor{title-color} 
                                             {\inserttitle}}\\
     \vspace*{.3cm}
     \vspace*{-.3cm}
     \hspace*{3.8cm}\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont \textit{\textcolor{title-
                                    color}{\insertauthor}}\\
     \end{centering}
     \vfill
}

% Aligning the contents in the Outline frame

% Assuming the Oultine page is always slide number 2

\usepartpagetemplate{
    \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{2}{%
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begin{centering}
    \vspace*{2cm}
    \hspace*{2.5cm}
    \fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont \textcolor{line-color!85}  
                                                  {\inserttocsection}
    \end{centering}
    \vfill
    }{}
}

\mode<all>
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a minimal, complete document showing your current settings?

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina a minimal .sty file

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina a minimal .sty file added above

Comment: But this is not what I was asking for; a minimal complete document should contain a concrete example of your actual code.